# Terms for male and female dragon?

Tags: dragons

Many animals have terms specifying a certain sex, for example *stag* and *doe* for deer. The term *drake* is usually used to signify a particular species of dragon (e.g. as opposed to a wyvern), but in "real" biology the term *drake* is used for a male swan. This got me thinking: is there a term for male and female dragons in the same way?

Comment: This question is far too broad. Please specify a work of Fantasy you'd like your answer sourced from, as there are no rules requiring author's to use the same term.

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/20567/31413

Comment: In order to prevent people from closing this answer as "too broad" (a judgement I don't agree with), you could change the title to something like *"In real languages, is there...?"*

Comment: A male swan is a cob, not a drake.  A wyvern is not a species of  dragon but a hybrid.  Apart from that, it is true that this is too broad.

Comment: I don't believe the question is too broad. I do, however, believe that it is off-topic. It is not about a specific universe and therefore is off-topic for this site. OP should try their luck on a different exchange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Drakon and Drakaina

Going to the very root of the word Dragon, it is derived from the Greek *Drakon*:

> *The word dragon entered the English language in the early 13th century from Old French dragon, which in turn comes from Latin draconem (nominative draco) meaning "huge serpent, dragon", **from the Greek word δράκων, drakon (genitive drakontos, δράκοντος) "serpent, giant seafish".** The Greek and Latin term referred to any great serpent, not necessarily mythological*
>
> <sub>***[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakaina_(mythology))***</sub>

The feminine form of this is the greek work *δράκαινα* - *[Drakaina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakaina_(mythology))*. 
In Greek mythology they tended to have feminine features and included *Delphyne*, *Campe*, *Python* and *Echidna*, and would not fit with the later European idea of the Dragon.

This can be seen by the painting of Apollo slaying Python on a 6th Century BC lekythos on display in the Louvre.

[image: ApolloPython]

Python has a serpent body and a female head.

However, male Drakon, didn't look like European Dragons either.

Here is Zeus slaying Typhon a Drakon. Note the male upper body, serpentine lower body and wings.

[image: ZeusTyphon]

Homer wrote about Drakaina when describing Apollo killing Python.

> *But near by was a sweet flowing spring, and there with his strong bow the lord, the son of Zeus, killed the bloated, **great she-dragon**, a fierce monster wont to do great mischief to men upon earth*
>
> <sub>***The Homeric Hymn to Apollo - Translated by Hugh G. Evelyn-White***</sub>

And in the original greek.

> *ξεστοῖσιν λάεσσιν, ἀοίδιμον ἔμμεναι αἰεί. 
>   300ἀγχοῦ δὲ κρήνη καλλίρροος, ἔνθα **δράκαιναν** 
>   κτεῖνεν ἄναξ, Διὸς υἱός, ἀπὸ κρατεροῖο βιοῖο,*
>
> <sub>***The Homeric Hymn to Apollo***</sub>

As Dragon is the anglicised version of Drakon, one could expect the anglicised version of Drakaina to be *Dragaina*.

Comment: These terms appear to be from mythology (sourced from wikipedia). Can you offer any actual examples?

Comment: Draikana aren't what you'd normally consider to be [female dragons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gwf0B7DiU4Y). They were [women with dragon features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echidna_(mythology))

Comment: @Valorum - i know but the actual word dragon comes from the Greek Drakon. Drakaina being the feminine of this does suggest it is the feminine version of a Drakon. Greek Drakons were not what you would consider a "Dragon" anyway, any large serpent or sea-creature was covered, a dragon, as we perceive it generally being a Norse invention.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is what comes of using wikipedia to answer an overly broad question. It's a poor answer to a poor question.

Comment: @Valorum - i've added a useage by Homer into it, does this improve it any?

Comment: Better, but that still ain't what the OP is asking.

Comment: This seems to be an example of the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). The OP was certainly not asking about masculine and feminine words for dragon on *non-English* languages.